# Docker does not find executable

Tags: docker, dockerfile, go-micro

I have an executable written in Golang, it starts and runs fine when started from the Linux-prompt. As you can see, the executable needs an XML file when started. But when started inside a Docker environment, I get error message:

```
standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

Let me tell you what I tried. First, this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
MAINTAINER Bert Verhees "xxxxx"
ADD archibold_ucum_service /archibold_ucum_service
ADD data/ucum-essence.xml /data/ucum-essence.xml
ENTRYPOINT ["/archibold_ucum_service", "-ucumfile=/data/ucum-essence.xml"]
```

I build it in this way:

```
docker build -t=ucum_micro_service .
```

Then I start it in this way

```
docker run --name=ucum_micro_service -i -t ucum_micro_service /bin/sh
```

When I do this, I get the error-message, as displayed above. Then I tried commenting out the ENTRYPOINT line, and then it builds OKAY and it starts the linux prompt, so I can query what is inside.
The executable is in it, and the data-file also. And the executable also has the right attributes (it is executable inside the docker-container)

Then I try to start the executable from the linux-prompt, inside the started container, and then I get again a message that the file is not found:

```
/ # ./archibold_ucum_service
/bin/sh: ./archibold_ucum_service: not found
```

For completeness, here is partly the directory-structure in the container:

```
/ # ls -l
total 17484
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root      17845706 Aug  3 13:21 archibold_ucum_service
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jul  5 14:47 bin
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Aug  3 14:29 data
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root           360 Aug  4 20:27 dev
drwxr-xr-x   15 root     root          4096 Aug  4 20:27 etc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jul  5 14:47 home
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root    ........
.......
```

So, what can be the problem. I am trying to solve this for over a day now. Thanks for support.

Comment: in the container's shell, try `ldd /archibold_ucum_service`. It should give you a list of dependencies.  Maybe some of those are present on the build host but absent in the (minimal) alpine linux container.

Comment: That must be the problem. I checked:
/ # ldd archibold_ucum_service
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fbddfacf000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fbddfacf000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fbddfacf000)

I think those libraries are indeed not there. Thanks. I am not in the position to work further on to this. But it is a good pointer to a solution. I let you know monday

Comment: There are other docker images that include go.... try searching for them on dockerhub and using that in place of plain alpine...  that's better than install the missing libs yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate this ;-)
Have a nice weekend

Comment: Use `debian:stretch`, should work fine.

Comment: debian:stretch works fine. Thanks